# I want to call a function on onclick but that function should be inside another function

Tags: javascript, html, function, scope

Javascript code:

```
function abc() {
  function def() {
    //do something
  }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<button onclick="def()">click me</button>
```

I get the error `def() is not defined`.

Comment: def is not part of the global scope, that's why you cannot access it with event handlers. you could return `def` from `abc` and call `abc` like so `abc()()`

Comment: you can do `onclick="abc()"` and in abc run `def()`

Comment: def is private scoped function of abc, what is significance of keeping def inside abc?

Comment: So are you saying that there is no way to accomplish this task?

Comment: @SaketSuraj to accomplish your task i have answered below

Comment: There is some important data in abc() function so that is being used in def(). So I need to put def() inside abc().

Comment: It would be best to use `addEventListener`

Comment: What is private, should be private.

Comment: @SaketSuraj did you try my answer?

Comment: @juanram0n yes I did try your solution, unfortunately it was not working.

Comment: @SaketSuraj I have just added a code snippet with the complete code in my answer, you can try it. It works. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 function def(){
         //do something
       }
function abc(playDef){
       if(playDef){
        def()
     }
    }
<button onclick="def(true)">click me</button>
```

For more functions you can pass arguments and manage if condition

Answer (score 0):

You only need to declare def in global scope:

```
function abc(){
   window.def = function(){
       console.log("hello, I'm function def");
   }
}
abc();
def();
```

But remember you need to call abc first to get access to def function. 
Hope this helps. Good luck.

I have completed my answer with a code snippet, you can try the working solution:

```js
function abc(){
   window.def = function(){
       console.log("hello, I'm function def");
   }
}
abc();
```

```html
<button onclick='def();'>Click Me!</button>
```